# django set template url from view

Tags: django

Is it possible to set a template url from a view in Django?

i.e. I have form with a cancel button and I want to use that form on multiple views but the cancel url will be different depending on what view the form is used in.

view:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['app'] = 'sites'
    context['view'] = 'site_list'
    context['cancel_id'] = 'this may or may not be set'
    return context
```

template:

```
{% if cancel_id %}
    <a href="{% url 'app:view' cancel_id  %}" class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</a>
{% else %}
    <a href="{% url 'app:view'  %}" class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</a>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just evaluate url at the view side using [`reverse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) and pass it to the template:

in view:

```
from django.urls import reverse

context['cancel_url'] = reverse('app:view', args=[cancel_id])
return context
```

in template:

```
<a href="{{ cancel_url }}" class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</a>
```